# `basename` argument not specified

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, frameworks

i created a new project by django restframework
the project name = frame
th project_app name= framework

fram.urls.py:

```
"""frame URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from framework.views import myviewset
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter();
router.register('task', myviewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

framework models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Task (models.Model):
    task_name=models.CharField(max_length='200')
    task_desc=models.CharField(max_length='200')
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializer.py

```
from .models import Task
from rest_framework import serializers


class TaskSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'task_name', 'task_desc')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializer import TaskSerializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Task


# Create your views here.
class myviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    query = Task.objects.all().order_by('date_created')

    serializer_class = TaskSerializers
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Task


admin.site.register(Task)
# Register your models here.
```

setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'framework',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

when i run th server in CMD
this error comes :

AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `queryset` attribute instead of `query` in your viewset. For example (class name case changed to comply PEP8):

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('date_created')

    serializer_class = TaskSerializers
```

Docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Also I recommend always specify `basename` when you register your viewsets. Like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter();
router.register('task', MyViewSet, basename='tasks')
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage

> `basename` - The base to use for the URL names that are created. If unset the basename will be automatically generated based on the `queryset` attribute of the viewset, if it has one. Note that if the viewset does not include a `queryset` attribute then you must set `basename` when registering the viewset.